# Finding where maximum of histogram occurs

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

If I have made a histogram of some data. How can I find out at which x-bin position the maximum occurs?

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = RandomReal[1000, {1000}];
Histogram[data, {20}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "count"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `HistogramList`.

Comment: Use `HistogramList` instead.

Comment: @JimB I was really surprised when I hit enter and *two* comments appeared :-)

Comment: @JimB and Szabolcs: Thank you. I get then a 2 d array of x bin positions and corresponding counts. I will never learn it: how can I pick from that the bin where the maximum occurs.

Comment: @Szabolcs My physics knowledge is enough to be dangerous:  could it be due to entanglement?

Comment: @Szabolcs: The length of of the two sub-lists from `HistogramList` is different. Why? `list = HistogramList[data, {20}]; Length@list[[1]]` is `51` and `Length@list[[2]]` is `50`.

Comment: A "bin" is an interval. The correct x-position would then be the middle of a bin with maximum cound, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you have lots of data from independent samples from some continuous distribution, then you might consider ditching the out-of-date histogram for a nonparametric density estimator (`SmoothKernelDistribution`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the comments:

```
(* get the bins and counts *)

{binx, counts} = HistogramList[data, {20}];

(* where does the max occur -- can be multiple *)

 maxBin = Position[counts, Max[counts]][[1]]

(* {26}  *)

(* what is its bin *)

maxIndex = binx[[maxBin]]

(* {500}  *)
```

Edit:

```
(* extract value from list *)

 maxIndex[[1]]

(* 500 *)
```

Comment: And `counts[[maxBin]] is then the corresponding value` … great

Comment: How can I convert `{500}` into the value `500`?

Comment: maxIndex[[1]]

(* 500 *)

Answer (score 3):

You can also post-process the output of `Histogram` to extract rectangle coordinates using `Cases`:

```
hist = Histogram[data, {20}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "count"}]; 
binsandheights = Cases[hist[[1]], Rectangle[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, ___] :> {{a, c}, d}, All];
```

Tallest four rectangles and the associated bins:

```
binsandheights[[Ordering[-binsandheights[[All, -1]], #]]] & @ 4
```

> {{{500., 520.}, 31.}, {{80., 100.}, 30.},{ {240., 260.}, 28.}, {{980., 1000.}, 28.}}

Comment: Incredible that also this is possible ...

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = RandomReal[1000, {1000}];

{b, c} = HistogramList[data, {20}];
```

Using [TakeLargest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeLargest.html) with its `Index` - option

```
{#, Extract[b, #]}& @ TakeLargest[c -> "Index", 1]
```

{{26}, 500}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HistogramList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) to extract the list of x-values for all bins (`binSpecs`) and their respective counts (`binCounts`). Note, that there is one more x-value than there are counts:

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = RandomReal[1000, {1000}];
{ binSpecs, binCounts } = HistogramList[data, {20}];

(* HistogramList will give: { {x0, x1, ..., x50}, { c1, c2, ... , c50 } } *)
```

We can easily transform the x-values into a list of tuples $(x_i^\text{left}, x_i^\text{right})$ giving the left and right x-value for each bin $i$. Then there will be as many bins as counts and we can then *link* each bin to its number of counts (using a rule for this seems quite natural):

```
bins =  binSpecs // Partition[#, 2, 1] &; (* partition the bin delimiters *)
histogramRules = bins -> binCounts // Thread;
```

Using [`MaximalBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) we can find the largest bin(s) according to their counts. Note: The function will return a list of bins and their counts if the maximum is not unique:

```
maxBins = histogramRules ~ MaximalBy ~ Last
```

> { {500, 520} -> 31 }

There is a unique maximum in this case and we can find the corresponding x-value by:

```
First @ maxBins /. Rule[binspec_List, val_] :> Mean @ binspec
(* or: maxBins[[1,1]] // Mean *)
```

> 510

If the maximum is not unique the bins can be extracted using `maxBins[[ All, 1 ]]`.

Note: Converting the x-values returned by `HistogramList` to binspecs (e.g. tuples) is imo more robust in the general case, as there may have been more complicated `binspecs` given.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Comment: @mrz You are welcome; your comment inspired me to make the solution a bit more readable (maybe).

Answer (score 1):

**Using `PositionLargest`:** (introduced with v13.2)

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = RandomReal[1000, {1000}];
{b, c} = HistogramList[data, {20}];

posh=PositionLargest[c]
```

{26}

```
b[[posh]]
```

{500}

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = RandomReal[1000, {1000}];
hlist = HistogramList[data, {20}];
```

Using `AssociationThread` and `MaximalBy`:

```
f = MaximalBy[AssociationThread[Range@Length@# -> #] &@#, Key] &;

{Keys@f@#2, #1[[Keys@f@#2]]} & @@ hlist

(*{{26}, {500}}*)
```